# Kubernetes pull from image private network / fails to respect /etc/hosts of server

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, hosts, ubuntu-22.04

I am running a small 3 node test kubernetes cluster (using kubeadm) running on Ubuntu Server 22.04, with Flannel as the network fabric.  I also have a separate gitlab private server, with container registry set up and working.

The problem I am running into is I have a simple test deployment, and when I apply the deployment yaml, it fails to pull the image from the gitlab private server.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: platform-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: platform-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: platform-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: platform-service
          image: registry.examle.com/demo/platform-service:latest
```

##### Ubuntu Server: /etc/hosts (the relevant line)

```bash
192.168.1.30 registry.example.com
```

##### The Error

```bash
Failed to pull image "registry.example.com/demo/platform-service:latest": 
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image 
"registry.example.com/deni/platform-service:latest": failed to resolve reference 
"registry.example.com/demo/platform-service:latest": failed to do request: Head 
"https://registry.example.com/v2/demo/platform-service/manifests/latest": dial tcp 
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443: i/o timeout
```

The 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is related to my external network, to which exists a domain name in the DNS, however all of my internal networks are set up to attach to the internal network representation, and 'registry.example.com' is a representation of my own domains.

Also to note:

```bash
docker pull registry.example.com/demo/platform-service:latest
```

From the command line of the server, works perfectly fine, it is just not working from kubernetes deploy yaml.

##### The problem

While the network on the server, and the host files on the server are configured correctly, the docker image is not resolving because when I apply it is not using the correct  IP (that is configured in hosts), rather a public IP that is a different server. And the reason for the timeout is because the public facing server is not set up the same.

When I run `kubectl apply -f platform-service.yaml` why does it not respect the hosts file of the server, and is there a way configure hosts inside Kubernetes.

(If this problem is not clear, I apologize, I am quite new, and still learning terminology, maybe why google is not helping me with this problem.)

The closest S/O I could find is:

[Kubernetes not able pull image from private registry having private domain pointed via /etc/hosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62940403/kubernetes-not-able-pull-image-from-private-registry-having-private-domain-point)

(SO Answer #1): hostAliases (this is for the pod itself, not pulling the image), also, installed through apt/package manager rather than snap.  With the rest of the answer suggests changing the distribution, which I would rather go with my current setup than change it.

##### Update

Attempts to add hosts to coredns not working either:
([How to change host name resolve like host file in coredns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65283827/how-to-change-host-name-resolve-like-host-file-in-coredns))

```
kubectl -n kube-system edit configmap/coredns
```

```
...
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
           lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        hosts custom.hosts registry.example.com {
            192.168.1.30 registry.example.com
            fallthrough
        }
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf {
           max_concurrent 1000
        }
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
...
```

deleted the coredns pods (so they are recreated)

and still the docker pull on the deployment fails with the external ip address instead of the internal address.

Comment: does pulling this image with docker pull works ?

Comment: @Shachar297 Yes as noted above, docker pull from the server works perfectly fine, the problem is when I create and apply the `deployment yaml` file it is not resolving from the server's /etc/hosts file at all, goes straight to the dns.  I think the problem is within either coredns or kube-dns, but can't seem to find where to add additional host/ip pairs for /etc/hosts

Comment: From my experience, you might be running kubeadm with containerd instead of docker, which both are using different engines, containerd will not use the /etc/docker/daemon.json configuration.

try looking at this  :

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/ .

Comment: You are right, as I recall it is in fact using `containerd`, reading through that page however doesn't provide any insight on how to get the custom hosts/ip's to be set (still digging though)

Comment: I am facing the same problem, please let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: Alan: based on the comment from @Shachar297 I am gathering there should be something to configure in /etc/containerd/??? but have yet to find it (or alternatively reconfigure kubernetes to use docker instead of containerd, which I'd like to avoid as well).. Still hoping for more suggestions to resolve this myself, but will add or accept an answer if I get it fixed

Comment: This does not seem like a programming-related problem; another Stack Exchange site like [sf] or [devops.se] might be a better place to ask.  Using `/etc/hosts` at all can be fragile due to issues like this, can you set up a DNS server in your environment instead?

Comment: @DavidMaze you are correct, I originally posted here as SO was where I found the most 'similar questions/answers'.  Per your comment however I have reposted to ServerFault.
https://serverfault.com/questions/1105843/kubernetes-pull-from-image-private-network-fails-to-respect-etc-hosts-of-serv

Comment: @DavidMaze Also, I'd be happy to add the hosts to the kubernetes cluster / network mesh / dns system even, but would rather not go as far as managing a DNS (relay) server

Comment: DNS in kubernetes and pods use /etc/resolve.conf of Kubernetes nodes and not using /etc/hosts of nodes.

Comment: @HamidOstadvali So that means I need to set up and manage an internal dns server to make this work?

Comment: @AaronMurray. yes. Also, maybe you can add this address in the Kubernetes coreDNS config.

Comment: @HamidOstadvali yeah that was more what I was looking to do was add a host, I didn't know where to add, but I will do some searching on coreDNS config and see if I can just add 1 or two specific hosts to properly resolve without the need for a separate dns server complicating things more

Comment: @Alan I finally resolved my issue (see my answer below), I hope this helps you resolve your problem as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After going through many different solutions and lots of research and testing.  The answer was actually very simple.

#### Solution in my case

The /etc/hosts file *MUST* contain the host for the registry (and possibly the entry for the gitlab instance as well) on *EVERY* node of the cluster including the master node.

```
192.168.1.30 registry.example.com
192.168.1.30 gitlab.example.com    # Necessary in my case, not sure required
```

Once I included that on each of the 2 slaves, it attempted to pull the image, and failed with credential issues (which I was expecting to see once the hosts issue was resolved).  From there I was able to add the credentials and now the image pulls fine from the private registry rather than the public facing registry.

##### Bonus: Fix for credentials error connecting to private registry (not part of the original question, but part of the setup process for connecting)

After fixing the /etc/hosts issue, you will probably need to set up 'regcred' credentials to access the private registry, Kubernetes documentation provides the steps on that part:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/